# Why does my array along a curve get shorter when I scale it down?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I have a spiral stairs array with the curve path. I parent the whole building (stairs and curve) to an empty and want to scale it all down. As I scale down the stairs get smaller.

**Without applying array modifier how can I scale down?**

[image]

[image]

Comment: Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/181816/how-to-imitate-scaling-a-mesh-in-edit-mode-without-edit-mode-ie-keeping-object